# SQL Server Analysis Services - How to filter just one measure by date and left another measure without filter?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap, measures

Hy guys!

I have the following scenario:

One cube with one dimension and two measures (sum of values). My user want to try to get the following results:

Choose one date column, that I'll call date1 from the dimension as a column title, choose both measures, that I'll call here sum1 and sum2.

So it will generate something like:

```
    date1              date1
   2016/01            2016/02
sum1     sum2      sum1      sum2
1000.00 1200.00   1100.00   1300.00
```

and continues like that. But with this results, he wants to filter just the sum2 measure by some date filtered from this date1 column, but he also wants to show all dates/sum1 values.

So, the right results should be like that if for example he filters date1 = '2016/02':

```
      date1            date1
     2016/01          2016/02
      sum1         sum1      sum2
    1000.00       1100.00   1300.00
```

I've no idea on how to achieve that. Can you guys give me any hint if that is even possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You could do MDX calculation. Just take one measure and filter it to specific date time, like that:

```
([Measure].[Name], [Date Time].[Dimension])
```